# Вывести имя компьютера в edit?

Tags: delphi

Как вывести имя компьютера в edit ? И где это прописать? В событиях edit?

Answer (score 3):

```
uses
  Windows;

function ComputerName: string;
var
  Buf: array[0..Windows.MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH] of Char;
  BufSize: Windows.DWORD;
begin
  BufSize := SizeOf(Buf);
  if Windows.GetComputerName(Buf, BufSize) then
    Result := Buf
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

> И где это прописать?

Там, где это требуется. Можно и по клику на кнопке вызывать.

Например, при создании формы:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := ComputerName;
end;
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ!!! хотелось бы чтоб как .exe запускался, в edit уже было написано имя компьютера.Куда для этого нужно положить скрипт?В events edit'a?

Comment: @АндрейАндрей Дополнил ответ, как пример, во время создания формы.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: @АндрейАндрей если ответ решает заданный вами вопрос - пометьте его, как принятый (поставьте "галочку")